# Returning Paths on Cubic Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk

Suppose we have a 3-edge-colorable cubic graph with $N$ vertices. 
How many paths of length $N$ exist that return to its origin?

Or putting it differently: What is "Pólya's Random Walk Constant" on such graphs?

Comment: Are you looking for \*bounds\* on Polya's random walk constant constant for such graphs?

Comment: Yes, that would be perfect.

Comment: In that case, please post at least a brief answer so that it can be upvoted by others (including me :)). You are even permitted to accept your answer.

Comment: @Srivatsan Hi again, it's been a while, but the question evolved as you could see when you follow the links in subsequent questions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what I was looking for is simply the diagonal entries of the $N$-th power of the adjacence matrix for the given graph. Maybe I should have noted that I'm dealing with finite graphs and I'm not expert enough to see if Pólya's Random Walk Constant makes sense here.

Comment: for a more worked-out answer, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/177699/19341)...